# having problems getting keyboard input in LÖVE

Tags: lua, love2d

heyo!

I'm trying to get input from my keyboard in LOVE2D but no input is being registered. getting no errors.

here's the code:

```
ESCdown=love.keyboard.isDown('escape')

function love.update()
if ESCdown then
    love.event.quit()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`love.update` is called every frame.

`ESCdown` is assigned a value once and then never changes.

Consider using keyboard events:

https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keypressed

It even gives an example for what you want to do:

```
function love.keypressed(key, scancode, isrepeat)
   if key == "escape" then
      love.event.quit()
   end
end
```

Comment: "Available since LÖVE 0.9.0 and removed in LÖVE 0.10.0
This variant is not supported in earlier or later versions."

can i still use it?

Comment: For `love.keypressed( key, scancode, isrepeat )` it says Available since 0.10.0. as far as I understand it there was an older version with 2 parameters that is no deprecated. give it a try